# Need help to reverse a string of words

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, ecmascript-6

How can I get following output when I pass following string in function as argument?

- input:   `"Reverse this line"`
- output: `"esreveR siht enil"`

#### this is my code

```
function reverseWords(string) {
    var wordArray = string.split(" ");
    var resultWordArray = [];
    var requiredSentance;
    wordArray.forEach(word => {
        if (word == " ") {
            var space = " ";
            resultWordArray.push(space);
        } else {
            var SplittedWord = word.split("");
            var reversedWordsLettersArray = [];
            SplittedWord.forEach(letter => {
                reversedWordsLettersArray.unshift(letter);
                var reversedWord = reversedWordsLettersArray.join("");
                resultWordArray.push(reversedWord);
            })
        }
    })
    var resultSentance = resultWordArray.join(" ");
    console.log(resultSentance);
}
reverseWords("Reverse this line");
```

which is returning this as output:

```
"R eR veR eveR reveR sreveR esreveR t ht iht siht l il nil enil"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're missing the fact that [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) _already exists_: `function reverseWords (string) { return string.split(' ').map(word => Array.from(word).reverse().join('')).join(' '); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using your code specifically, you are very close with what you are trying to do.  You just need to move the declaration of the `reversedWord` variable out of the `forEach` loop, update inside the `forEach` loop, which will eventually be defined with the entire reversed word.

```
function reverseWords(string) {

var wordArray = string.split(" ");
var resultWordArray = [];
var requiredSentance;

wordArray.forEach(word => {

  if (word == " ") {
    var space = " ";
    resultWordArray.push(space);

  } else {
    var SplittedWord = word.split("");
    var reversedWordsLettersArray = [];
    var reversedWord; //define variable here 

    SplittedWord.forEach(letter => {
      reversedWordsLettersArray.unshift(letter);
      reversedWord = reversedWordsLettersArray.join("");
    })
    resultWordArray.push(reversedWord); // push it here
  }
})

var resultSentance = resultWordArray.join(" ");
  console.log(resultSentance);
}


reverseWords("Reverse this line");
```

Answer (score 10):

You can split the string into words and map through each word, splitting it into a character array and reverse the array, then join back the words into a single string. Like this:

```
string.split(' ').map(s => s.split('').reverse().join('')).join(' ')
```

To explain the code:

```
string.split(' ')
```

This line splits the whole string into array of words, `"Reverse this line"` becomes `["Reverse", "this", "line"]` (note that the spaces are gone). Keep in mind that double spaces will be still split as a single space.

Since we now have an array, you can iterate the whole string using the `.map` function. It works similarly to how you've tried to use the `.forEach`, with the difference that the `.map` function will return a new array with modified values which are returned in each iteration of the `.map` callback function. Make sure to return something, or the values will be `undefined`! The arrow function from ES2015+ has implicit return as you see in the example above, but if you were to use `=> {...}`, the block needs an explicit `return` statement to work.

The code of the `.map` function callback

```
s => s.split('').reverse().join('')
```

Receives a `s`, which is a single word from the array above, splits the word by empty string, which is a workaround to split a string into characters. For example, `"Reverse"` becomes `["R", "e", "v", "e", "r", "s", "e"]`. The `.reverse()` function's name is quite descriptive, it just reverses the array. But be careful! It mutates the array, so if you call the `.reverse()` function on a random array, it will be reversed from that line on. This could cause some issues if you're not careful. Lastly, the `.join('')` puts the reversed array of characters back into a single string word.

And finally the `.join(' ')` at the end puts the mapped array, which now contains reversed words, back together with spaces in-between, similarly to how `.join('')` puts the array of characters back into a single word.

Comment: You can make it even simpler using regex: `str.match(/./g).reverse().join('')`

Comment: @Pedro that would throw an error if there were two consecutive spaces.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts How is that? It seems to be working for me. I'm using Chrome version 63.

Comment: @Pedro is this similar to how you tested? `"Reverse  this line".split(' ').map(s => s.match(/./g).reverse().join('')).join(' ')`

Comment: @Pedro this doesn't work correctly. Take another careful look at the expected output. The OP wants to revert each word, not the whole string.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I've tested like this: `"Reverse this line".match(/./g).reverse().join('')`. It seems to be matching the expected output. Right now, I can't think of a test case where this code would fail.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Just now I've realized that I was wrong.

Comment: @Pedro are you sure? I've copied the code and ran in the chrome console. The output is `"enil siht esreveR"`. The answer states the expected output is `""esreveR siht enil"`. You have to reverse the words one by one, not the whole string. What you're doing is the same as `.split('').reverse().join('')`, just might seem a bit more fancy with the regex.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak it's not the same thing. `.split('')` won't fail on empty string, while `.match(/./g)` will.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you're correct, but it doesn't even matter that much since the core logic of the suggested the alternative solution is not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting approach that doesn't require a call to `.map()`, if you think outside the box a bit about the string processing:

```js
function reverseWords(string, delimiter = ' ') {
  return string
    .split('').reverse().join('')
    .split(delimiter).reverse().join(delimiter);
}

console.log(reverseWords('Reverse this line'));
```

If you reverse character-by-character on the first pass, you can then split the string by the word delimiter (in this case `' '`) and reverse the words to put them back in the original order on the second pass.

After benchmarking this approach, I've found that [it is twice as fast as the currently accepted answer](https://jsbench.me/xwjddeszx7/1).

Another nice feature about this function is that you can specify the word delimiter as the optional second argument:

```js
function reverseWords(string, delimiter = ' ') {
  return string
    .split('').reverse().join('')
    .split(delimiter).reverse().join(delimiter);
}

console.log(reverseWords('Reverse this line', '\t'));
```

Comment: Why might one not want to use `.map`?

Comment: I didn't say it was a bad thing, I was just setting my answer apart from the current one by highlighting how the approach is fundamentally different. But to answer your question, `.map()` does have overhead of context switching for each word, while this does not. I'll benchmark and find out which one is faster, because it's also possible that two passes might still be slower than one pass with overhead.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but the only thing I see is a nice play with `.split` + `.reverse` + `.join`, which at the end results, in my opinion, a less understandable code. The only real benefit customizable `delimiter`, this might be nice if this code is used in more different cases than the one described in the question.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak my hypothesis was correct, check out [the benchmark](https://jsbench.me/xwjddeszx7/1).

Comment: There is often a tradeoff between readability and performance. The goal here is simple. The use case for this function is probably not going to be in a codebase where extreme performance is required, it just doesn't seem like this kind of problem. It might be, but before knowing that the performance of some part of the code is the issue, I see performance optimizations over readability as a non-argument.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak in the case of unreadable micro-optimizations, I agree, but this isn't a micro-optimization, it's actually a fundamentally different algorithm that still uses a canonical functional approach. I think the perceived unreadability is simply because most people wouldn't think of the transformation as these two steps, but rather the two steps in your algorithm, so it's _unintuitive_, but not _unreadable_. I think the 100% performance boost from doing this at least warrants consideration.

Comment: In my opinion, intuitiveness of code is a big part of understanding the code and understanding the code is often dubbed as readability. If the performance isn't a critical factor, I prefer code easy to understand, without having to think and figure out how the parts of it work. One can assume the wrong thing and that's how the bugs are born. I don't like bugs in my code, there's enough of them as is, no need to leave a chance to introduce more for some performance gain. If the function is called only couple of times a second, the 100% gain doesn't do much, it's perceived as instant either way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive method that just iterates once over the string:

```
function reverseWords(string){
  return (function f(str, i, reversed){
    if (!str[i])
      return reversed;

    if (str[i] == ' ')
      return reversed + ' ' + f(str, i + 1, '');

    return f(str, i + 1, str[i] + reversed);
  })(string, 0, '');
}

console.log(reverseWords("Reverse this line"));
```